# Swipe between activities

Tags: android, android-activity, scroll, swipe, android-viewpager

I want to swipe between activities, but I'm not sure what best practices would be.

Should I throw everything in at once and scroll from each activity?...and does that create memory problems?

Or am I better off implementing an actual swipe?

Are there other methods I should consider?

The end-game will be 10-15 Activities filled with HTML, making up a magazine...so I want the user to be able to swipe from each article (which will be 1 per activity) to another.

Thanks!

Comment: Why not use an endless full screen gallery with the articles buffered into a list and scroll through the gallery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also use [GestureDetector](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.html) and [OnGestureListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.OnGestureListener.html) to launch a new Intent when a fling is detected with public boolean onFling().

Personally I would use the ViewPager as described by [kabuko](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9470015/503508).

Answer (score 6):

You want the [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html). Read [this](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html) blog post on it.