# Swipe animation when switching layouts android

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I wanted to ask  how i can  create a good swipe animation when switching from one xml layout to an other in android?
It would be very kind if somebody could gibve me an example code. Thank you very much!

Comment: Do you really mean one layout to another or one activity to another? Also, the default animation is sliding in anyway, so what do you want that's different?

Comment: Yes from one layout to an other. The provlem is im pretty new to android development so i dont know exactly how to switch from a layout to an other. I would like to set it like: you swipe from right to left to get to the next layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html). It's been asked in [many other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9469951/swipe-between-activities/9470015#9470015) before. Read [this blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html) for more information.